# Choosing correct authentication aproach when working with Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook, api, ads, facebook-login

I am very new to Facebook Ads API so some help or advices about best practices I can use in my case would be appreciated a lot.

**The situation:**
We have multiple clients that are running advertising campaigns on social sites and Search Engines like Facebook, LinkedId, Google Adwords, Bing and etc. They want to have information from all their campaigns in one database and use this database to run various reports in order to manage their campaigns better (move money from one campaign to another and have better results). So basically we need to perform daily (or should I say nightly) sync. Also we need to mark adds in Facebook that are part of campaigns that are running via our tool (also not a problem to do once logged in). This is done automatically.

That is not a problem in many platforms - we use Google and Microsoft API to connect to the platform, read required data on daily basis or do some changes to URLs automatically.

**The question**
I was a bit surprised to find out that in Facebook Ads API the only way to authenticate is via tokens that expire quite fast (long term tokens last for 60 days). I am wondering if it is possible to authenticate via API with user name and password or obtain the ticket that is not expiring. The reason - most of our processes will run on nightly basis so any interaction with user to get fresh ticket is not possible.
Asking for permission every 60 days also seems like not an option and offline_access privileges that would suit us perfectly are no longer supported as I understood correctly from the documentation.

So what are authentication options? Is the only possibility to ask user to re-confirm our access rights every 60 days? Is it possible to get access permission once and live with it until user revokes it, or this is not possible?

Thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook did an exception for ads api access tokens. It is still possible to get neverending access token. Reed more here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal. Also, you can check access token type, expiration date and other params here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. Our access tokens shown as Expires: Never.